# How to read files in a folder that isn't the current folder?

Tags: matlab

I'm making a program which need a reference folder with `.txt` files inside. Those files are read automatically. In the next step, the user is asked to choose a file and the program will read the specified file.

The thing is, I want the reference to be in a different folder (which will stay the same). If my current folder is the one containing the user's data, how can I read my reference files?

Here's the codeline for the automatic file opening part, as it is right now :

```
fichierref = 'H:\MATLAB\Archive_08112012';
files = dir(fullfile(fichierref, '*.txt'));
numberOfFiles = numel(files);
for d = 1:numberOfFiles
   filenames(d) = cellstr(files(d).name);
end
```

It does open the files automatically, but only if my current folder is the Archive_08112012.

EDIT:

I'll add this. This is how I open the files.

```
headerlinesIn = 11;
delimiterIn=' ';
if numberOfFiles > 1
for i=1:numberOfFiles
     data = importdata(filenames{i},delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

It has exactly the same line if numberOfFiles = 1, but there is no for loop.

Comment: It looks like this is the code for the automatic detection of files, not the opening part! please add that too since you're having troubles with that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug your code and you'll quickly see what's going wrong:

```
files = dir(fullfile(fichierref, '*.txt'));
..
filenames(d) = cellstr(files(d).name);
```

you're building a cell array of the filenames (note: *names*, not the full path). If you had inspected the contennt of this array, you'd have seen what's going wrong with the file loading:

```
 data = importdata(filenames{i},delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

you issue `impordata` on the filename; when you don't specify the full path, matlab goes looking for the file in the current directory (or other directories added to the matlab path, not important right here).

It must be clear by now you'll want to switch to using importdata with the full path of the file you're after. Do this with fullfile:

```
other_directory = 'c:\whatever\it\might\be'
data = importdata(fullfile(other_directory,filename{i}),delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

Answer (score 2):

To refer to a file outside your current working directory, you need the full path (or relative path) to the file. You can build paths using [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html), as you did in your example code. Use the full (or relative) path instead of just filenames when calling your `importdata` function.

Comment: Thank you too! Gunther Struyf said the same thing as you but with a bit more details ahah

Answer (score 1):

You should keep using `fullfile`. I just post an example taken from http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html

```
f = fullfile('myfolder','mysubfolder','myfile.m')

f =
myfolder\mysubfolder\myfile.m
```

Comment: I don't see you're point... I keep using it. What's the difference here?

Comment: in your question you say `I want the reference to be in a different folder`, right? with `fullfile` you may build your path. I just refer to what you wrote.

Comment: fichierref = 'H:\MATLAB\Archive_08112012';
files = dir(fullfile(fichierref, '*.txt'));

Isn't that exactly what I'm doing?

Comment: probably I did not understand your question properly: seemed to me that you only wanted to switch reference folder from `H:\MATLAB\Archive_08112012` to another one.

Comment: No. This is my reference folder, but I can read it only if it is the current folder. I read 2 types of data : references, and the user's data. The current folder will be set to the user's data's folder. Therefore, I must be able to access the reference folder without it being the selected folder in Matlab.

Comment: Usually when I want to access files outside my `working directory` I make use of fullfile. Probably it is not your case, but the second answer you've got is partially advising the same.